# XSS vulnerable, even when I am using encoding

Tags: html, xss, html-entities

I have a input field, where I am using `htmlentities` to encode values.

```
$value=htmlentities($value);
```

The value stored in db is:

```
&quot;/&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(document.cookie)&lt;/script&gt;&lt;br class=&quot;
```

But when I am displaying the above text to the user, the alert is executed. How can I prevent that?

Comment: If your data is already HTML-encoded (e.g. `&lt;`), applying `htmlentities()` to it will encode it twice (`&amp;lt;`). Both `&lt;` and`&amp;lt;` are very different from `<`. I'm sure you have a wrong diagnostic (or this is not the actual code).

Answer (score 0):

There are more things that could happen:

- You have some other code doing alert, other than the "comment"
- - Look at outputted page and try to find, where it is called
- You have old page in cache
- - Clear cache and try again
- Using some "html entities decode" function, which converts entities to actual characters
- - Just don't use this function